# Scala: Pattern Matching Based on Self Defined Types

Tags: scala

As you know one of the great thing about the language is the way it does pattern matching:

```
val frontman ="Mick Jagger"

frontman match {
  case "Mick Jagger" => "Rolling Stones"
}
```

However matching based on basic types (`Int`, `Boolean`, `String`, `Float`, etc.) is not a very clean way to me. Is there a better way to create my own types, which they hold the value of the basic type, 
and then I do the pattern mathcing based on that?

Obviously I can have a `val rollingStonesFrontman = "Mick Jagger"` and then match based on that; but would like to have a more maintainable approach.

**Why It Is not maintainable**: It is not maintainable, because it is much better, for the other developers in the future, to make a model out of it, and then use it in the pattern matchings all over an application.

**Initial Attempt**:  The cleanest way I could factor out the basic type value, and use it within the pattern matching:

```
trait Band{
  val frontman: String
}

object RollingStones extends Band{
  override val frontman = "Mick Jagger"
}

val toBeMatched = "Mick Jagger"

toBeMatched match{
  case RollingStones.frontman => println("We got the Rolling Stones singer!")
}
```

Is there a more cleaner way to write the above code?

Comment: Efficient how? It's not immediately clear to me the way in which the given example is lacking in efficiency?

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco You can imagine I have this pattern matching all over an application, and would like to model it out; for the sake of maintainability to other developers.

Comment: Watch out: the word "efficient" tends to be ascribed a very specific meaning in computer science (not related to maintainability). Still, please post a bit more code. It's still difficult to understand the nature of the maintainability problem you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, take a look at "Matching on case classes" here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html#matching-on-case-classes

From there:

```
abstract class Notification
case class Email(sender: String, title: String, body: String) extends Notification
case class SMS(caller: String, message: String) extends Notification
case class VoiceRecording(contactName: String, link: String) extends Notification

def showNotification(notification: Notification): String = {
  notification match {
    case Email(email, title, _) =>
      s"You got an email from $email with title: $title"
    case SMS(number, message) =>
      s"You got an SMS from $number! Message: $message"
    case VoiceRecording(name, link) =>
      s"you received a Voice Recording from $name! Click the link to hear it: $link"
  }
}
```

Update: It's hard to know what you're looking for without a more concrete example... maybe this:

```
trait Frontman
case object MickJagger extends Frontman

trait Band
case object RollingStones extends Band

frontman match {
  case MickJagger => RollingStones
}
```

Update, slightly cleaner:

```
abstract class Band (val frontman: String)

object RollingStones extends Band(frontman = "Mick Jagger")

val toBeMatched = "Mick Jagger"

toBeMatched match {
  // no need for if guard
  case RollingStones.frontman => println("We got the Rolling Stones singer!")
}
```

The if-guard is not needed since you can use an identifier directly in the pattern match. But it requires that it be a **stable** identifier (ex: val, object, literal... not var or def). So the original `def frontman` would not have worked. If the identifier had been just a `val` without an object prefix, then it would have needed backticks to differentiate it from a pattern variable.

Comment: Good point on creating abstract class but the example provided is good for refactoring out the interaction between the classes/methods and sending the `Notification` type to a method; but this is not what Im after: replacing a basic type's value with a self type.

Comment: @DaveRose Can you clarify what you mean by "replacing a basic type's value with a self type"? Can describe a concrete use case?

Comment: Something like `case mySelfDefinedType => anotherSelfReturnType` where these two hold the basic type value. Perhaps I should use a `Trait` here.

Comment: Thanks for the last update, approved the answer. Could you also please add some explanation to it as well, especially how to define the model so that we dont use the if statement within the case matching.